# What happens to someone who dies without any thoughts as per Hindu scriptures?

Tags: scripture, bhagavad-gita, belief, atma, death

Bhagavadgita 8.6 says यं यं वापि स्मरन्भावं त्यजत्यन्ते कलेवरम्। तं तमेवैति कौन्तेय सदा तद्भावभावितः।।8.6।। Which means whatever entity one thinks of at the time of death, he attains the state of that very entity.

Hypothetically, What will happen if a Human dies without thinking of anything? Where will he go?

Comment: Can you please tell in your question :Is person unconscious/in sleep/or awake with no thoughts? Like what case are you expecting answers for

Comment: @Hope An answer which explains all of them on a case by case basis would be preferred.

Comment: What you mean where will he go? He will go based on his karma

Answer (score 1):

> Which means whatever entity one thinks of at the time of death, he
> attains the state of that very entity.

It is not very easy to die **without thinking about anything**. It doesn't naturally happen. This is why Yoga needs to be practiced.

> 1. Now concentration is explained.
> 2. Yoga is restraining the mind-stuff (Chitta) from taking various forms (Vrttis)

~ Yoga Sutras of Patanjali Chapter 1

When you can't restrain your mind in a simple painless meditation for 2 minutes, restraining the same during a painful death is highly difficult. That's why we practice - yoga - equanimity of mind in various situations of life - through karma yog, bhakti yog and gyan yog. The three yogas help to purify the mind so that it calms down and specially during the time of death - prevents taking various vrittis based on attachment and pain and break the cycle of death and birth.

Comment: Yes, It is difficult to be completely thoughtless, But what happens if a person can hypothetically do that at the time of death? The answer doesn't address this.

Comment: @vsejkgf The answer was to tell you that - **you cannot do it** at the time of death when you are in pain, if you can't do in control of self in painless sitting around. Do you think the pain of suffocation would let you override your willpower during the time of death?

It is NOT completely difficult to be thoughtless, in fact the goal of **kaivalya samadhi** is to reach that ultimate state, after which you'll never be born again.

Comment: What about those who give up their life on their own volition with Yogic processes? Do they also experience pain while leaving the body?

Comment: @vsejkgf Depends on the technique. Mostly no.